# Questions regarding RSADigestSigner and DSAsigner

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I am new to Bouncy castle. I have some questions regarding signers package in bouncy castle. For RSADigestSigner, is our message hashed internally or do we have to hash it on our own? Another similiar question is for DSASigner, it does not have a built-in digest, so do we have to pre-hash our message before using DSASigner?

Here are two of my codes:

```
 // RSADigestSigner

        // Pick the hash, SHA512 in this case
        SHA512Digest digest = new SHA512Digest();

        // Create a RSADigestSigner to sign
        RSADigestSigner sign = new RSADigestSigner(digest);

        // Initialize for signing
        sign.init(true, privKey);

        // Pass data to sign
        sign.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

        // Generate the signature
        try {
            signature = sign.generateSignature();
        } catch (DataLengthException | CryptoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

```
// Create a DSASigner to sign 
        DSASigner sign = new DSASigner();
        
        // Initialize DSASigner
        sign.init(true, privKey);
        
        // Hash the message
        
        
        // Generate the signature
        signature = sign.generateSignature(input);
```

Comment: One more question might be why RSADigestSigner must contain Digest but DSASigner or ECDSASigner does not?

Answer (score 1):

For [`DSASigner`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/signers/DSASigner.html) you must compute the hash yourself, whereas for [`RSADigestSigner`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/signers/RSADigestSigner.html) the hash is computed internally to the class. This is possible because the constructor for `RSADigestSigner` takes a [`Digest`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/Digest.html) argument. But the parallel to `RSADigestSigner` is [`DSADigestSigner`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/signers/DSADigestSigner.html), not `DSASigner`, so you probably want to use `DSADigestSigner`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Really appreciated! But what if i want to hash on my own then use RSA to sign? I noticed that in Bouncy Castle, there is no such thing called RSASigner, there is only RSADigestSigner.

Comment: There's not really any support for that. It's possible to do something similar using `GenericSigner` and passing your own custom `Digest` object that does nothing except copy the message. You could also just implement your own `Signer`. The problem is that you don't get a properly formatted PKCS#1 signature because such a signature requires a hash OID in the signature. So do you need these signatures to be interoperable with standards-compliant verifiers?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Yes, I want to use these signatures to be interoperable with standards-compliant verifiers. I wonder if it is better for me to do JCA but with provider "BC" which allows me to apply hash first and sign with "NonewithRSA".

Comment: @Alex: That's a good point, you can use `Signature.getInstance("NoneWithRSA");`

Comment: Thanks again. But do you have any ideas about how we can achieve it using bouncy castle only?